# Need a comparitive analysis on the WPF Grids of Devexpress/Telerik/Exceed/Infragistics

Tags: c#, telerik, devexpress, infragistics

Where can i find a comparitive study on the wpf grids of Devexpress/Telerik/Exceed/Infragistics ? i need to check their pros and cons,

•   WPF Grid with Sorting, Filtering, Grouping, Exporting and Print preview/Print.
•   The number of rows per grid would range from 3K to 30K. The number of grids at any time would range from 2 to 12.

Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never seen a comparison online but you can download all the suites for review.

I have used the DevExpress and Telerik controls and while the WinForm controls from DevExpress have the edge the Telerik controls for XAML / ASP platforms are much better and use data virtualisation heavily. The WPF grid demos load 1,000,000 rows so your data size should not be a problem.

Can't comment on the other providers

Comment: Be careful with that comparisson as I can see most of the results referring to Telerik are incorrect / out of date.